# Onsen UI sample app bad display and on iOS with Cordova

Tags: cordova, onsen-ui

I just started evaluating Cordova, Onsen UI and IONIC.
Using recent versions and sample applications, without any modifications I managed to properly deploy ionic-Cordova app on iOS.
Unfortunatelly I have a problem with Onsen UI (using the same environment) - (onsen sliding menu template) application deployed on iOS behaves bad - it goes under the status bar, half of title text is not displayed and the whole app including title bar is going down while swiping.
I believe this is causes by some viewport/CSS settings or maybe iOS app.

Here is how it looks when swiped down:

[image: screenshot from iPhone, iOS8.1]

Comment: Hi, what device and which OS version, did you use? I would like to test.

Comment: Ios 8.1 on iPad 3, iphone 5s, ios simulator